# Correct way to store large collection of Mongo data in time series so it can easily be queried?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

if we're saving a lot of data (say several hundred MB) to a Mongo collection for a single day's data, **what's the best way to put that in a new DB to save that data across time (and so it can be queried to see changes over time)**?  I've been saving data to a collection similar to the structure below. The prices change daily, and so far I've been replacing the old data with new data each day. Instead, I'd like to be able to keep the existing structure, but save each day's collection along with the old data to a new db that let's me do queries across time. What's the best way to structure this in a new DB so that I can easily query unit pricing data across time, but don't have to change how the current db is being saved? **Should I make each day's data a separate collection in the new DB and name each collection by date, or put each day's data in it's own document in 1 very large collection, or something else?**

Current structure (represents snapshot of prices for a given day):

```
Collection: 
[{name: 'Property A',
latlng: [1,2],
propertyData: [{blah, blah}],
units: [
    {unitNum: 1, 
    pricingData: {
        1/1/2020: 
            {3-month-lease: 1500,
            4-month-lease: 1400, 
        ... [more prices for different lease lengths]
        1/2/2020: [prices for different lease lengths],
        ... //lots of data for prices on each date
        3/31/2020: [somedata]} }
    {unitNum: 2, pricingData: [pricing data for unit 2]
    ... [more data on units for this property]
    ]
},
{name: 'Property B',
latlng: [1,2],
propertyData: [{blah, blah}],
units: [
    {unitNum: 1, 
    pricingData: {
        1/1/2020: 
            {3-month-lease: 1500,
            4-month-lease: 1400, 
        ... [more prices for different lease lengths]
        1/2/2020: [prices for different lease lengths],
        ... //lots of data for prices on each date
        3/31/2020: [somedata]} }
    {unitNum: 2, pricingData: [pricing data for unit 2]
    ... [more data on units for this property]
    ]
}
... //data for many other properties
]
```

Again, above represents a snapshot for 1-day's data. I'd like to have a db that has data for every day with data like the above so that I can see how the pricing data for units change across time.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: In case it helps, each day's data would have on the order of 300mb of data (data on thousands of units and lots of pricing data for each unit). To date this 300mb of daily data is in a single collection (again, I'd like to save each day's data together somehow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new collection is probably not a good thing. For MongoDB, each collection and index are themselves files. Too many of those can cause file handling and memory issues.

Instead, use a date/time value to distinguish the date plus whatever other fields you need for the search and the sorting.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, so 1 collection with many date documents? And this should be fine, even if each date document in the collection has a bunch of nested values and is on the order of 300mb? So the collection would be something like:
[ {date1: {300mb of data}, date2: {300mb of data}, date3: {300mb of data}... }]

Comment: You can't have more than 16 MB worth of data in a single document.  So, having 300 MB of data in a document is out.  

Also, if you thinking having a BLOB in the document, then I would suggest to actually add the data as fields in the document if you can.  

If the data is truly binary, then you might want to either use the GridFS feature of MongoDB. You might be better served to store the reference to binary data in MongoDB, but the actual BLOB as an object is an object storage system, like S3.

Comment: Many documents can share a date.  You probably have other identifying fields like batch number or customer number that can be used to find a specific batch of data.

Comment: Hi @Steve, thanks, appreciate it; I've edited the code section in the original question to clarify how the data is structured. There's no images/media files or anything like that, it's all pricing data. In the collection there's something like 4,000 documents representing properties (buildings); each property may have 10-50 units, and each unit has price data on 30-90 different dates, and each date has maybe 12 different lease lengths. So ~4k properties x 50 units x 90 dates x 12 lease lengths. That is the data I would like to save each day and be able to query. Recommendations? Thx!

Comment: Do you think it'd make sense to just add a field to each day's document showing which day that data came from? So if right now my db has 1 collection with ~4k documents (representing 4k properties), the new one with data for each day will have 4k documents x # of days of data, and each document will be the same size as in my current collection (plus one field for the date the document was saved)

Comment: Yes, you can use date to distinguish between imports. You may also want a fields added to identity a batch number and source as well.